# Calling javascript return value function from the android activity

Tags: android, cordova

Can some help me in getting the return value of a javascript function from within android native code. The answer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514039/calling-javascript-function-from-the-android-activity) helped me to get the alert value of the javascript function from android java activity class but not the return value. In the following js function, if I do

```
echo window.localStorage["email"]
```

I get an alert in my java activity class. However

```
return window.localStorage["email"]
```

does nothing and I instead I get the error cannot convert from `void` to `String` for my

```
MyActivity.activity.sendJavascript("userEmail();")
```

---

Here is my js function:

```
function userEmail() {
return window.localStorage["email"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function userEmail() {
    var email=’’;
    email=window.localStorage["email"];
    return email;
}
```

Comment: I am asking how the to get the return value from android java activity class. It works good if I do:    alert('window.localStorage["email"]') but not return window.localStorage["email"];

Comment: Try:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298597/how-to-get-return-value-from-javascript-in-webview-of-android