# Handling native event in javascript android

Tags: javascript, android

I have written a native class to download from the internet, and I want to call that code from JavaScript. I can call the native code from JavaScript in webview, but I don't know how to call the native event in JavaScript.

This is the native code :

```
public class DonwloadTask extends AsyncTask<URL,Void,Long>  {
        private OnTaskCompleted listener;
        private String result;

        public DonwloadTask(OnTaskCompleted listener){
            this.listener=listener;
        }

        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            int count = urls.length;
            long totalSize = 0;
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    // Read all the text returned by the server
                    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(urls[i].openStream());
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
                    String resultPiece;
                    while ((resultPiece = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        resultBuilder.append(resultPiece);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // if cancel() is called, leave the loop early
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            // save the result
            this.result = resultBuilder.toString();
            return totalSize;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // update progress here
        }
        // called after doInBackground finishes
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            //Log.v("API", this.result);
            // put result into a json object
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(this.result);
                // call callback
                listener.onTaskCompleted(jsonObject);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
</code>
And this is interface for event 

<code>
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    String onTaskCompleted(JSONObject result);
}
</code>
And this is class wrapped the DownloadTask
<code>
    public class NativeApi implements OnTaskCompleted {
        private DonwloadTask task;

        public NativeApi(){
            task= new DonwloadTask(this);


        }

        public void startDownload(String urlStr){
            URL url= null;
            try {
                url = new URL(urlStr);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String onTaskCompleted(JSONObject result) {
            return result.toString();
        }
    }
 </code>  
    And javascript to call native code
 <code>
function startDownload(url){
    NativeApi.startDownload(url);
}
</code>
```

How can I subscribe onTaskCompleted in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call as follws:

```
MyActivity.activity.sendJavascript('yourFunction();');
```

Check this link for further info [Calling javascript function from the android activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514039/calling-javascript-function-from-the-android-activity)